# sed regex to extract field and construct new

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have this output from aws:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=c4.xlarge" | egrep -e "Value" -e "PrivateIpAddress" | grep bot -B1
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.44"
                            "Value": "bot-30",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.106"
                            "Value": "bot-29",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.167"
                            "Value": "bot-1",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.161"
                            "Value": "bot-14",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.235"
                            "Value": "bot-17",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.54"
                            "Value": "bot-28",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.234"
                            "Value": "bot-12",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.43"
                            "Value": "bot-5",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.50"
                            "Value": "bot-27",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.124"
                            "Value": "bot-20",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.247"
                            "Value": "bot-26",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.113"
                            "Value": "bot-8",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.190"
                            "Value": "bot-11",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.184"
                            "Value": "bot-13",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.253"
                            "Value": "bot-25",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.254"
                            "Value": "bot-2",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.199"
                            "Value": "bot-21",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.130"
                            "Value": "bot-10",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.59"
                            "Value": "bot-18",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.4"
                            "Value": "bot-7",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.213"
                            "Value": "bot-9",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.214"
                            "Value": "bot-3",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.200"
                            "Value": "bot-24",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.148"
                            "Value": "bot-15",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.146"
                            "Value": "bot-6",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.94"
                            "Value": "bot-4",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.150"
                            "Value": "bot-23",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.81"
                            "Value": "bot-16",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.155"
                            "Value": "bot-22",
--
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.2.102"
                            "Value": "bot-19",
```

I want to format into following

```
10.100.2.44    bot-30
10.100.2.106   bot-29
10.100.2.167   bot-1
```

reason i need in that format because i want to add all those hostname and ip address in `/etc/hosts` file. this is just small list but we have pretty long list too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe your `aws` command to this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/PrivateIpAddress/N;s/.*"\([^"]*\)"\n.*"\(.*\)",.*/\1\t\2/p'
```

Comment: you were first among all so `answered`

Answer (score 2):

If use of pipe is allowed, we can try below solution -

```
awk '{ORS=(/,/?RS:FS)}1' f|awk -F'[,]|["]|[:][ ]' 'NR>1{printf "%-15s %s\n", $5,$10}'
10.100.2.44     bot-30
10.100.2.106    bot-29
10.100.2.167    bot-1
10.100.2.161    bot-14
10.100.2.235    bot-17
10.100.2.54     bot-28
10.100.2.234    bot-12
10.100.2.43     bot-5
10.100.2.50     bot-27
10.100.2.124    bot-20
10.100.2.247    bot-26
10.100.2.113    bot-8
10.100.2.190    bot-11
10.100.2.184    bot-13
10.100.2.253    bot-25
10.100.2.254    bot-2
10.100.2.199    bot-21
10.100.2.130    bot-10
10.100.2.59     bot-18
10.100.2.4      bot-7
10.100.2.213    bot-9
10.100.2.214    bot-3
10.100.2.200    bot-24
10.100.2.148    bot-15
10.100.2.146    bot-6
10.100.2.94     bot-4
10.100.2.150    bot-23
10.100.2.81     bot-16
10.100.2.155    bot-22
10.100.2.102    bot-19
```

Answer (score 1):

Found dirty way to do it.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=c4.xlarge" | egrep -e "Value" -e "PrivateIpAddress" | grep bot -B1 | paste -d " " - - - | awk -F[\"] '{print $4 "\t" $8}'
10.100.2.44 bot-30
10.100.2.106    bot-29
10.100.2.167    bot-1
10.100.2.161    bot-14
10.100.2.235    bot-17
10.100.2.54 bot-28
10.100.2.234    bot-12
10.100.2.43 bot-5
10.100.2.50 bot-27
10.100.2.124    bot-20
10.100.2.247    bot-26
10.100.2.113    bot-8
10.100.2.190    bot-11
10.100.2.184    bot-13
10.100.2.253    bot-25
10.100.2.254    bot-2
10.100.2.199    bot-21
10.100.2.130    bot-10
10.100.2.59 bot-18
10.100.2.4  bot-7
10.100.2.213    bot-9
10.100.2.214    bot-3
10.100.2.200    bot-24
10.100.2.148    bot-15
10.100.2.146    bot-6
10.100.2.94 bot-4
10.100.2.150    bot-23
10.100.2.81 bot-16
10.100.2.155    bot-22
10.100.2.102    bot-19
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS="--"; FS=":"; OFS="\t" }  # delimiters and such
       { for(i=2;i<=3;i++)                 # process $2 and $3
             gsub(/ *"|".*/,"",$i)         # remove to first " and from second "
             print $2,$3                   # output $2 and $3
       }' file                             # or aws ... | awk ...
10.100.2.44     bot-30
10.100.2.106    bot-29
```

Answer (score 1):

A single awk should enough (best would be to have a sample of aws result for testing):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=c4.xlarge" \
 | awk -F '[":[:blank:]]+'!(/"PrivateIpAddress"/||/"Value".*bot/){next}{if($2=="PrivateIpAddress")IP=$3;else printf("%s\t%s\n",IP,$3)}'
```

With comment

```
 # field separator is any combinaison of ": or space
 awk -F '[":[:blank:]]+'
    # eliminate line (skip) that dont containt "private" or "value" with "bot"
    !( /"PrivateIpAddress"/ || /"Value".*bot/ ){ next }
       {
       if line is Private, take IP value (only keep the last found)
       if ( $2 == "PrivateIpAddress" ) IP = $3
        else {
           # print line that have bot with last know IP
           printf( "%s\t%s\n", IP, $3)
           }
       }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $4,$8}' RS=-- FS=\"
```